# Some site's do not allow embedding via IFRAME, is there any possibility?

Tags: html, iframe

I've noticed that some sites do not allow embedding via iframe HTML tag.

Is there any other way that could work ? I've also tried to load with HTML object tag but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bypass embedding sites like google in an iframe because they add x-frame-options headers (deny or sameorigin).  Browsers that support those headers simply won't allow it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

If you just need to get data from a page and show it, you could get the data server-side, but this is probably not your intentions.

Good luck.

Comment: Well I know about scraping, but what I need is to load the whole page like in an iframe. Thanks anyway